# Bootstrapper Application name appears multiple times in "Programs and Features"

Tags: wix

I have created a BootStrapper application (BA) that has some required setups to run and an MSI to run that we create. The BA has the bundle shown below:

```
<Bundle Name="FOO Installer"  Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="FOO International" UpgradeCode="33AAE528-A1F0-45DD-AAF5-A83B4B749F10">
```

When the BA is run multiple times on the same machine the name "FOO Installer" appears once, in Programs and Features, for each time the BA is run. I want to be able to run newer versions of our BA and install over the top of any current installation, but I want the installer to be listed only once in Programs and Features. What can I do to get this result?

Answer (score 2):

You have to increment your version (first three part) for upgrade.

> Bundles with the same UpgradeCode have an upgrade relationship.The 
>   higher version removes the lower version. Same versions but built at 
>   different times can end up in the situation you describe.

http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Bootstrapper-Upgrade-Detection-td7580471.html